# inline-block parent wrapping to anchored divs

Tags: html, css

I want to overlapping, relatively positioned divs, and for a parent div to wrap them, such that it fits both (as if they weren't overlapping). So something like this:

```
+------------------------+
|+----------+            |
||  Child 1 |            |
||      +---------------+|
||      |               ||
|+------|   Child 2     ||
|       |               ||
|       +---------------+|
+------------------------+
```

So, the parent should always fit child 1 and child 2. Child 1 and Child 2 are themselves not a set width or height, their size is a function of their contents. Technically, the image above does more than I care about, since I plan for both divs to be at 0,0. I can't absolutely position them, because then they won't grow the parent.

Comment: you can add a negative margin

Comment: Will the NW coordinates of both children always be the same?

Comment: I've tried that, but given that the I don't know ahead of time the width of any of these components, I can't make it work. To be more concrete, both children want to live at 0,0. So, the second child would need a negative left and top margin, but that would require knowing the total height which I don't have.

Comment: @BenM: yes. Basically I want two divs, anchored at 0,0 NW, where the parent's width is max(width0,width1), and height is max(height0,height1).

Comment: Unfortunately you're not going to be able to achieve that without JS.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried ?